# Como utilizar Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles en Vue

Tags: vue3, mapa, leafletjs

Estoy intentando crear un mapa Offline utilizando Leaflet con el complemento Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles en Vue.

Utilizando leafletjs funciona perfectamente pero lamentablemente necesito de estar conectado a Internet.

[image: Codigo Funcional]

Para su uso Offline he intentado agregar la librería Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles en la carpeta src he importarla luego de importar leafletjs.

Para la importación uso el código

```
import '@/assets/lib/sql.js'

import '@/assets/lib/mbtiles.js'
```

Por último intento acceder con al archivo mbtiles en la ruta local

```
L.tilelayer.mbtiles('./mapas/mapa.mbtiles).addTo(map)
```

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme lo agradecería

Comment: Además de mencionar que el código debe ser mostrado siempre _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976): lo que estás haciendo es cargar como "pedazos" (los _tiles_) de una imagen muchísimo más grande (que corresponde al mapa global). En tu caso particular, estás utilizando OSM. ¿Consideraste tener tu propio servidor de _tiles_?

Comment: Sí se lo del texto, el problema es que subí la pregunta desde el teléfono. El problema es que no he logrado descargar los Tiles para montar mi propio servidor, he visto alternativas como MOBAC pero el área que me permite descargar es muy pequeña.

Comment: ¿Consideraste como opción la descarga desde [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/)?